# Compilation error in mvc partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, partial-views, temporary-files

[image]

> Server Error in '/' Application. Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'models'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'projadmin' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 29:     
Line 30:     
Line 31:     public class 
   _Page_Views_applicationengineer__projreportslist_cshtml : 
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<projadmin.models.report>> {
Line 32:         
Line 33: #line hidden
```

> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\445350b2\af487c21\App_Web__projreportslist.cshtml.81d00718.fc3benth.0.cs
>   Line: 31
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> Show Complete Compilation Source:
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2053.0

Comment: Post code pls !!!

Comment: It looks pretty obvious, You have used Class `projadmin.models.report` in cshtml file but this namespace `projadmin.models` doesn't exist. Go to `Report` class and check the Namespace /folder structure.

Comment: thank u sangram-nandkhile for ans but i solved my mistake just before 10min and now i saw same solution from you also so i guess i m on perfect solution..  now just i want to check my application working properly or not. but thank u so much for reply